# Extra properties allowed for lambdas but not for functions

Tags: typescript

I'm seeing very puzzling interaction between lambdas and partial types. Excerpt:

```js
interface IContext {
  a: number;
  b: string;
}

type PFactory = () => Partial<IContext>;

const pf1: PFactory = () => ({}); // no error, expected
const pf2: PFactory = () => ({a: 1, b: "foo"}); // no error, expected
const pf3: PFactory = () => ({a: 1, b: "foo", c: 3}); // NO ERROR, UNEXPECTED
const pf4: PFactory = () => ({c : 3}); // error, expected
```

Absense of error in pf3 is completely unexpected and goes against the similar (reasonable) situation:

```js
type Factory = () => Partial<IContext>;


function f1(): Partial<IContext> { return {}; }
function f2(): Partial<IContext> { return {a: 1, b: "foo"}; }
function f3(): Partial<IContext> { return {a: 1, b: "foo", c: 3}; }; // error, expected
function f4(): Partial<IContext> { return {c : 3}; }; // error, expect
```

What is going on here?

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED24IA8zIDeAUMsnAFzIgCuAtgEbQDcpyDVAzmFKAOasAvsWIwaIBGGDZkCABSTcVDNkj4AlEVnZOmADYQAdNCiYoCsLnXNkwsRKkyADhaXIACnChS4egDwqOPgAfJqE2iC6BsZQpuaK1rYiYACeTigAYohgZinIALzIcpr5wR5ePv6BamDBrKnpHlmSuQVFJWWe3sC+AVhBtawi8oSCiQD048gmZgA007jpkhAAJsQjlMgAjPMcyABEMJiY+2OsG1Q77FSHx-vzCFQAzGfIk9OxcwtLkGsjj8gXhMpjMoPM8D9ViIXKNrMQYZsrntbiczvC5IREbsbkcTg9nq93qDwYsIMs1jCAUCbETPmDvmTfiJ1joCE4tlQupU+qo8LU2qNzqzkE4AEycio9Kr9GplQqYy7Yg6405CyJsp4S7q9ap8uVELHXZV3fGAwQ0kF0kmQv7CpwAFi13N1IQFCGQBItHzi1sZUOGdpgHKa2VahWKBTKGLRCED4pDLSgeXDHSKCu2SpRpzhsfVIpgmoTOSTbQjpTThuRKtN1LeUwAcgB5ZAAUQASm3G235gBVestgAa7hb6AAKi2ACIsvNOGCOoth9qRtPugnA71fCF+taicSSaQgZBB4pOqU8gZlcJQCBgGhQQ+CpL2fcyGCik-lbXS3muq83u8PpWOJ3OaT57o4h4Fh+XJni6-J-re94GoqRpZjWoF2OBB5Hva0GSjqMp6lo16IQ+q5mjYwhAA)

*Update 1*

All this seems to happen because the following type cast is not considered problematic:

```js
const a: () => ({a: number, b: string, c: number}) = () => ({a: 1, b: "foo", c: 3});
const b: () => ({a: number, b: string}) = a;
```

So the second question now also is: can I change PFactory definition any how to force compiler to complain?

Comment: https://lemoine-benoit.medium.com/why-does-typescript-sometimes-fails-to-type-check-extra-properties-fd230ebbc295